# Autofac ignores registration conflicts

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, autofac-configuration

I have the following test

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    public interface IMy { }

    class MyClass : IMy { }

    class MyClass2 : IMy { }

    [Test]
    public static void Go()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<MyClass2>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolved = container.Resolve<IMy>();
        Console.WriteLine(resolved);
    }
}
```

Why it does not throw exception when implementations are obviously in conflict ? And how to make it throw exception if such a conflict found ?

**UPDATE**
Solution with registration checking is almost Ok, but 
there is simple situation when it fails:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
    }

    public interface IMy
    {

    }

    class MyClass : IMy, IPlugin
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    class MyClass2 : IPlugin
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    public class SingleRegistrationModule : Module
    {
        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
            IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, 
            IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            foreach (var service in registration.Services)
            {
                var registrations = componentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(service);
                if (registrations.Count() > 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        "Can't register '{registration.Activator.LimitType}' as '{service}'" + 
                        " because '{registrations.First().Activator.LimitType}' is already registered");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public static void Go()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<MyClass2>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterModule<SingleRegistrationModule>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolved = container.Resolve<IMy>();
        Console.WriteLine(resolved);
    }
}
```

In this case nobody resolves IInitializable so it is acceptable to have multiple implementations. Moreover there are scenarios when mulltiple implementation is OK, for example IPluginToSomething

Answer (score 7):

The reason that Autofac doesn't throw an exception is because Autofac considers multiple registrations for the same interface to be part of a collection. Example:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMy>();
builder.RegisterType<MyClass2>().As<IMy>();
var container = builder.Build();
var collection = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMy>>();
Console.WriteLine(collection.Count()); // prints "2"
```

In case multiple registrations are made, a call to `Resolve<IMy>()` will resolve only one of them (either the first or the last, but I always forget which one it is). I personally consider this a design flaw in Autofac (and the other DI containers), because this causes your application to fail silently, instead of failing fast. In [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) the choice has been made to strictly separate the registrations of collections (as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections)) to prevent these types of configuration mistakes.

Comment: I fully agree with you and I also tried to resolve the collection, but how to override this flawed default behaviour ?

Comment: @AlexIlyin: I don't think you can easily override this, but perhaps the Autofac guru's can answer that.

Comment: I checked the revolving sequence, Autofac will use the last one when inject.

Answer (score 2):

As [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134037/814735) said, *Autofac* will consider multiple registration of a same service to be part of a collection.

If you don't want this behavior, you can add a check using an *Autofac* module :

```
public class SingleRegistrationModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, 
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        foreach (var service in registration.Services)
        {
            var registrations = componentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(service);
            if (registrations.Count() > 1)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"Can't register '{registration.Activator.LimitType}' as '{service}'" + 
                    $" because '{registrations.First().Activator.LimitType}' is already registered");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can register the module using :

```
builder.RegisterModule<SingleRegistrationModule>();
```

The exception will be thrown when the container is being built.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there seems to be a problem. This solution throws too many exceptions...

Let's suppose types are registered using 
.RegisterType<MyClass2>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

And some of them support IDisposable, IEnumerable or any other interface nobody going to resolve.

This solution would report error for these interfaces.

Comment: Of course I can support a list of exception interfaces, but it is not a scalable solution

Comment: I've even tred to listen evens like ResolveOperationBeginning and InstanceLookupBeginning, but these events do not seem to expose the requested interface

Comment: It is so strange that there is no some simple solution, from my point of view 100% of Autofac users should face the problem

Comment: You are the first one I heard with this problem. Could you describe tout problem ? Maybe a [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I've updated the initial question because large code fragments are not allowed in comments. The point is that sometimes it is a valid situation when one interface has multiple implementations. It is a problem only when one tries to resolve such an interface

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help me. I am new to Autofac so I have to ask stupid questions :)

Comment: IMO you should not use AsImplementedInterfaces.

Comment: And do note that this `SingleRegistrationModule` completely disables registration of collections altogether, which might not be desirable.

Comment: If I do not use AsImplementedInterfaces. then how should I register my types ?

Comment: With the as method